# Azure Blockchain , Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined

Tags: azure, uri, blockchain

I am starting with Azure Blockchain. When i call VSCode command: "Blockchain: Show Welcome Page" or other commands. Then this error show up. How can i fix it. Thanks!

OUTPUT:

```
"[Azure Blockchain] Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined".
Error show up in screen: "Command 'Blockchain: Show Welcome Page' resulted in an error (command 'azureBlockchainService.showWelcomePage' not found)"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow Minh Phan! Please take some time to read about [what makes a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

I would advise checking that you have the [requirements](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-blockchain-ethereum/wiki#system-requirements) for this plugin installed before trying to run the Blockchain commands from with Visual Studio Code.

I was able to install and open the welcome page with the following versions:

- Visual Studio Code 1.52.1
- NPM 6.14.8
- Node.js 12.18.4
- Git 2.29.2.windows.3

If you already meet the prerequisites I would try uninstalling the plugin and then closing Visual Studio Code, then re-opening and attempting to install the plugin and run the command again. Failing this, you may get better help by raising in issue against the repository for the plugin on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-blockchain-ethereum/issues).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to makes a good question on next time. I think this error happened because I deleted the old project folder to make a new project.